# Heroku current_page? breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, heroku

I have tried everything and I failed to fix this so I came here :). I have the following working to perfection locally, but for some reason it breaks when I push it to heroku.

I my application.html.haml template:

```
%body
    = render :partial => 'layouts/topbar'
    - if user_signed_in?
      - if current_page?(url_for(:controller => 'posts', :action => 'index'))
        = render :partial => "layouts/flash_messages", :locals => {:flash => flash}
        = yield
        #go-top
          Scroll to Top
      - else
        .container.main
          = render :partial => "layouts/flash_messages", :locals => {:flash => flash}
          = yield
    - else
      .container.main
        = render :partial => "layouts/flash_messages", :locals => {:flash => flash}
        = yield
```

Can someone please point out at my errors? Or knows why this is breaking in heroku? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I am using a cedar stack app and in my heroku logs I have, although that path does exists:

```
2012-06-14T08:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/user_root" for XXX.XX.XXX.XX at 2012-06-14 08:39:59 +0000
2012-06-14T08:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"posts"}):
2012-06-14T08:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:27:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml___40461595758832869_62063220'
2012-06-14T08:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-06-14T08:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-14T08:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_topbar.html.haml (3.6ms)
2012-06-14T08:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-06-14T08:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /user_root] miss
2012-06-14T08:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (1.0ms)
2012-06-14T08:39:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms
```

Comment: how is it breaking?  what error messages are you getting?  what heroku stack are you on?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I edited my original post to show what you asked :)

Answer (score 1):

Do "heroku run rake routes" and make sure that there is actually a route that corresponds to :controller => "posts" and :action => "index".

no idea about why that would work differently on the two machines, but you might also compare "rake routes" run locally.  might be worth adding the output to your question if it isn't obvious.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc092a9cba5fceec38358072e50e09250cf58840/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L588) you don't need the url_for part?

Try:

```
if current_page?(:controller => 'posts', :action => 'index')
```

Comment: I fixed it, but I am still getting the same results. It is very strange. Is there any other way to accomplish what I am trying to do? Thank you for answering!